# SWT - How to change the Window Class name? wm_class

Tags: java, swt

At present all my Java GUI applications have `SWT.SWT` as their window class.  I would like for some of them to be linked as sub-windows in menu applications such as Cairo-Dock.  This is the third column of the out put from `wmctrl -lx`.

I have tried using the `Display.setAppName()` method in an attempt to set this name.  Neither `Display.setAppName` or `display.SetAppname` will change the app class from `SWT.SWT` to the class name I'm tring to set.

When I use the lower case `display.setAppName` it produces this warning in the Eclipse IDE:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The static method setAppName(String) from the type Display should be accessed in a static way   WBTest.java /javaTools/src/javaTools    line 31 Java Problem
```

**Code Sample:**

```java
package javaTools;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class WBTest {
    private Table table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WBTest window = new WBTest();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        display.setAppName("myapplication");
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        shell.setSize(560, 426);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        // table.setBounds(49, 21, 241, 158);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableItem row = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        row.setText("This is a test.");


        shell.open();
        // shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My research shows how to do this in **Python**, which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.set_wmclass ("Hello World", "Hello World")
win.set_title ("Hello World")
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with **SWT/Java**.
Is there something else I need to add to this function to make it work, or is there a differernt function that is specific to setting the application's class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether to remove this question or provide the answer.  I had worked on it since yesterday and was still trying lots of variations.

One finally works.  Apparently, the line has to appear in the code before declaring the `Display`.

**This works:**

```java
package javaTools;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class WBTest {
    private Table table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WBTest window = new WBTest();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display.setAppName("myapplication");
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Display.setAppName("myapplication");
        Shell shell = new Shell();
        shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        shell.setSize(560, 426);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");

        table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        // table.setBounds(49, 21, 241, 158);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableItem row = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        row.setText("This is a test.");


        shell.open();
        // shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```